# Formatted string in list

Tags: python

What is its solution or another way?
I wrote a strings list as shown before this I wanted to format it and include options then I wanted to print (by taking input from user) its index but on the terminal error was thrown that 0 or 1 index is not present in list.

```py
options = ["a) 31\n b) 32\n c) 33\n d)34", "a) Energy\n b) Motion\n c) Motion and Energy\n d)Nothing"]
questions = [f"Our brain is consists of ..... bones:\n{options.index(1)}",
              f"Physics is the study of .......\n{options.index(2)}"]

q_1 = input(questions[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`options.index(1)` searches `1` in the list and returns its index. This is not what you seem to want.

You seem to want to get the first element of `options`, which is done with `options[0]` instead.

It is `0` instead of `1`, because Python lists are indexed starting from `0`, not `1`.

You are doing this correctly when you index into `questions`.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code with options[1] insted of options.index(1)

```
options = ["a) 31\n b) 32\n c) 33\n d)34", "a) Energy\n b) Motion\n c) Motion and Energy\n d)Nothing"]
questions = [f"Our brain is consists of ..... bones:\n{options[0]}", f"Physics is the study of .......\n{options[1]}"]

q_1 = input(questions[0])
```

The index method searches if the value you provided is in the list ie it options.index(0) checks if an element with value 0 is present and returns its index

To get the element at index 0 use list[0]

Comment: Thanks! For your support